# Is there a package in R for statistical relational learning

Tags: r, statistics, machine-learning

I just searched on google and r-project.org but couldn't find anything.

Is there a package in R for statistical relational learning?

Link to wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_relational_learning

Comment: No offense to you, but that is a very vague page.  What is it that you are seeking to model or which models are you seeking to use?  Doug's answer is pretty good, btw.  If you can clarify your next steps (data or models), it may be easier to give a more focused answer.  A lot of what I've found on SRL is very poorly conceived, so it may be the case that there are R packages that do SRL (and, more importantly, the approach you seek), though not marketed under the SRL buzzword.

Comment: There was a fellow PhD student at a conference who said to me that 'statistical relational learning' cannot be done with R. I had the feeling that this is not true, but I was neither familiar with the topic nor could I find more information with google. thanks for you feedback too!

Comment: That's pretty amusing.  Maybe you could have the same fellow define SRL?  Or perhaps the answer will come back that it cannot be defined in English?  ;-)  It does not appear to be in the mainstream of machine learning.  It looks like it's merely an odd synonym for graphical models, which are certainly supported in R - [there's a task view for that](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html).

Comment: @Iterator i agree completely--the term "SRL" is horrible (not the OP's fault, indeed, the ambiguity is what makes the Question interesting.) My sense is that this term is domain-specific (perhaps, like the term "path analysis" in psychometrics). i had never heard/seen this term until i scanned the wikipedia article linked to in the OP.

Comment: so what is the best academic conference in statistics to follow for possible applications in machine learning? Because I have the feeling, that some parts of machine learning are not state-of-the-art for a top level statistician.

Comment: hmmm. There is a book called Introduction to statistical relational learning ( http://books.google.com/books?id=lSkIewOw2WoC ). I'm just guessing, but is there anything called "multi-relational learning"?

Comment: @mrsteve There isn't one conference or one journal.  The interesting results could appear via any number of conferences or journals.  I could start a list, but this is a question that's better addressed on the statistics SE site.  I encourage you to post this question on that site.

Comment: @Iterator. thank you for your offer on a list of conferences. that would really help me. I just started a question on statistics SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few actually.

On [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/), look at the [gRaphical Models Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html).
Under each header is a listing of R Packages subsumed under that subject header--the first being *Representation, manipulation and display of graphs*.

Scroll down this page to the last three section headers:

***Miscellaneous: Model search, specialized types of models etc***.,

***Bayesian Networks/Probabilistic expert systems***; and

***BUGS models***, just below it.

Under these three headers are a total of ***16*** R Packages (seven, three and six packages, respectively). Within these nine, you should have no trouble finding a couple most suited for your project.

The only one I have personally used is ***bnlearn***, a Package for *Bayesian network structure learning*. This is not my field, so I recall that the Package documentation (Manual and Vignette) are excellent and include working code examples.

Finally, for *visualizing* these models, I recommend highly the R bindings to the excellent *Graphviz* Library; the R bindings are gathered in the R Package, [RGraphviz](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rgraphviz.html). RGraphviz is not available on CRAN but rather on **[Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/)**; it depends on [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org).

Comment: thank you very, very much for your answer! I was on a conference and someone said 'statistical relational learning' cannot be done in R. And I said yes, it can, but could not find any relevant information with google, nor did I have more time because I was attending the conference.

Comment: I am really stunned. GraphViz is OPEN SOURCE with an Eclipse Public License!! (Only since the summer of 2011) This was definitely not the case when I last used GraphViz. Superb. So now it's an OSI and FSF approved license that's easy to use and less restrictive. Finally GraphViz will be easy to install and package/distribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, actually. Doug's answer is inherently misleading. If someone's looking for non-R implementation of the requested models, I may provide [this link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/kersting/plmr/PLMR_repository).